# Write a function that uses the short cut formula to calculate sums of squares of a vector using R

Tags: r

I only know how to writing a function that squares a number.

```
sums.squares<-function(dat){
squares <- dat^2
sums<-squares
return(sums)}
```

Comment: `norm(1:10,'2')^2` should solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to sum your result up before.

```
sums.squares<-function(dat){
squares <- dat^2
sums<-sum(squares)
return(sums)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is(are) an alternative function(s) although not exactly a shortcut:

```
expo<-function(n){
  force(n)
  function(x){
   res<-x^n
   sum(res)
  }
}
square<-expo(2)
```

Testing the `square` function

```
mydata1<-c(1,2,3)
square(mydata1)
#[1] 14
```